# How to define classes such that there will be only one Product object and multiple Product Details objects in c#

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

Can someone give example how to "define classes such that there will be only one Product object and multiple Product Details objects in c#"?

Comment: We're not a code writing service. We're here to help you with your code. Please have a go and post what you come up with. We can then help you fix it if there's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more information:

```
public class Product {
   public Product() {
      Details = new List<ProductDetails>();
   }
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<ProductDetails> Details {get; private set;}
}

public class ProductDetails {
   public string SomeDetailedText {get; set;}
}
```